# openweathermap API has section in square brackets, can't call that json data in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, retrofit

So I am trying to make a weather app, the API *works* but only in certain areas. For now I am just trying to make a Toast of the API to make sure it works before I go on to do the rest of the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Retrofit
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        OpenWeatherMapClient api = retrofit.create(OpenWeatherMapClient.class);
        Call<DailyWeather> call = api.getDailyWeather();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DailyWeather>()
        {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DailyWeather> call, Response<DailyWeather> response)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (response.body().getWeather().getDescription()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for( Weather w : response.body().getWeather())


                {
                    Log.d("Weather", w.getId().toString());
                    Log.d("Weather", w.getMain().toString());
                    Log.d("Weather", w.getDescription().toString());
                }

            }
```

**So this is my MainActivity.java, if I replace getWeather().getDescription()) with .getCoord().getLat()) it works.** The only thing I have noticed is the API section for weather is in sqaure brackets.

So if I run my API searching for 'Birmingham,uk' this is the json (after going through an online parser for easy reading'

```
{
"coord":{
"lon":-1.9,
"lat":52.48
},
"weather":[
{
"id":802,
"main":"Clouds",
"description":"scattered clouds",
"icon":"03d"
}
],
"base":"stations",
"main":{
"temp":282.57,
"pressure":1008,
"humidity":76,
"temp_min":282.15,
"temp_max":283.15
},
```

> For reference I'll leave the Coord and Weather classes I have in case
>   the error is in there.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Coord {

    @SerializedName("lon")
    @Expose
    private Double lon;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private Double lat;

    public Double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

}
```

And

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Weather {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("main")
    @Expose
    private String main;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    @Expose
    private String icon;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(String main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

}
```

**And the DailyWeather class as requested**

```
 public class DailyWeather {

    @SerializedName("coord")
    @Expose
    private Coord coord;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = null;
    @SerializedName("base")
    @Expose
    private String base;
    @SerializedName("main")
    @Expose
    private Main main;
    @SerializedName("visibility")
    @Expose
    private Integer visibility;
    @SerializedName("wind")
    @Expose
    private Wind wind;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    @Expose
    private Clouds clouds;
    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private Integer dt;
    @SerializedName("sys")
    @Expose
    private Sys sys;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("cod")
    @Expose
    private Integer cod;

    public Coord getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }

    public void setCoord(Coord coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Integer getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(Integer visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    public Wind getWind() {
        return wind;
    }

    public void setWind(Wind wind) {
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    public Clouds getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    public Integer getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(Integer dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public Sys getSys() {
        return sys;
    }

    public void setSys(Sys sys) {
        this.sys = sys;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(Integer cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }
}
```

Comment: the square brackets produce a list, the curly brackets produce an object with key/value pairs

The list can then be a value of a key/value pair

Comment: Can we have a look at your DailyWeather class?

Comment: Just edited my post to include it, Levi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weather variable is a list, so to access it you should do:

```
List<Weather> weatherList = response.body().getWeather();
if(weatherList!=null && !weatherList.isEmpty()){
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (weatherList.get(0).getDescription()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You weren't able to do `getWeather().getDescription()` because `getWeather()` returns a list. So you'd need to select an element in the list to only then do `getDescription()`.